# Converting data into specific table - Google Sheet - problem

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a specific table based on data downloaded from a certain tool.
The best way to describe my problem is to check the table with example data and result that I would like to get (link to the Gsheet and screenshot attached below).

Part of the data like "type of activity" sometimes can be done a few times, but in the "result" table they need to be summed up.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u4dMoUWg6r3eUVZ9qEfkWiMS8iLgDr_TwnjS1GEXKTU/edit?usp=sharing

here is a screenshot
[google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8f7N.png)
and a link to It in case if it wont work https://pics.one.ly/wbuXpg40

Answer (score 0):

Use `QUERY()` function with `pivot` clause. Try-

```
=QUERY(A11:D25,"select B, sum(D) group by B pivot C")
```

[image]

Comment: [`=QUERY(A10:D25,"select B, sum(D) group by B pivot C ")`](https://i.imgur.com/EYji6R9.png)

Comment: can you order within this pivot | Order by Sum(D) Asc / desc | ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a pivot table

[image]

check data : you have typed clinet instead of client

Comment: Ye i see. Anyway thank You for help :) Pivot table is the key